# finding orthogonal complement in the given cases

Tags: linear-algebra

let $V = \Bbb R_5[x] $ with the inner product defined by $\langle p(x),q(x)\rangle =\int_{-1}^1 p(x)q(x) \,dx$. find $W_\bot$ if

**(1)** $W=\{p(x)\in \Bbb R_5[x] :p(x)=p(-x)\}$

**(2**) $W=\{p(x)\in \Bbb R_5[x] :p(0)=p^1(0)=p^2(0)=0\}$

**(3)** $\{p(x)\in \Bbb R_5[x] :p^1(x)-p(x)=0\}$

in first case,we get $W_\bot=$set of all odd polynomials of degree less than or equal to 6.but,i am really stuck in finding the other two...please,answer in detail...

thanks a lot....

Comment: You'll need to explain your notation. Presumably by $\mathbb{R}_5[x]$ you mean polynomials with real coefficients and degree $\le 6$, but what are $p^1$ and $p^2$? Also, what have you tried for the second two questions?

Comment: @rogerl;by $\Bbb R_5[x]$,i mean polynomials with real coefficients and degree ≤6 and $p^1$,$p^2$ rfer to the first and second order derivatives and i am not able to solve (2) and (3)...that's why i asked it...